# CRM Dynamic Online Odata Query via Powershell

Tags: powershell, oauth-2.0, odata, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I am trying to Query Microsoft Dynamic CRM 2013 Online with Powershell.
The following code should work - anyone know why I cant authenticate correctly

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$yesterday = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-1).ToString('s') 
$url = "https://development.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/IncidentSet?`$filter=CreatedOn gt datetime'" + $yesterday + "'"
$url
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Credential $cred
```

The Url works in a browser when I am authenticated.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Looks like Microsoft Dynamic Online used OAuth bearer token, so the only way is to

Answer (score 0):

Script mentioned above works fine, when Credential Request popup appears provide username as 'domain\username' and correct password.
Additionally response can be seen on PowerShell screen by adding one more line at last: Write-Host $response

Comment: Is there anything else that needs to be done in order to get this to work with a site using ADFS and Microsoft Dynamics CRM IFD?